# why doesn't the website shrink to the target resolution

Tags: html, css

I had recently created a [personal site][1].

I wanted to design such that no matter how low the target resolution would be my site would shrink to fit the whole screen without needing to scroll down. I used `%` values so that it fits on any target resolution.

Here is the design of the website with all the main properties.
![site design description][2]

My problem is that when I make the resolution of the browser small, the content doesn't shrink to fit the screen.

This is what happens when I shrink the browser resolution.
![Boom][3]
Why is this happening?

Here are the css properties

```
#myPageBody
{

    padding: 3% 15% 5% 15%;
}

#myPageNav
{
    text-align: center;
    padding:0%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    font-weight :bold;
    font-size:150%; 
}

#myPageNav span 
{

    padding-right:2%; 
}

.page
{
    position:fixed;
    width:65%;
    height:70%;
    padding:1%;
    font-size:200%;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you reduce the screen size, the font-size doesn't change, hence it occupies same space as usual and breaks up.

Comment: Nice observation..I never looked at it..how to make font change according to browser resolution then!

Comment: @Anirudha http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom in or zoom out, the pixels are increasing or decreasing respectively according to their provided percentages.

Try giving `max-width` , `min-width`(*In pixels*) , `max-height` and `min-height`(*In pixels*) properties to them.
I may be wrong but this is a good practise.

For Example:

```
max-width:100%;
min-width:1024px; /* The least resolution to be considered */
max-height:/*desired percentage or pixels */
min-height:800px; /* The least resolution to be considered */
```

Comment: i agree but for the sake of animating the page, i cant provide min or max..But can u tell me how to make font change according to browser resolution cuz I think that is the problem as pointed out by @I-love-php

Comment: do you mean keeping it constant though the screen resizes?

Comment: Not constant..I want the font-size to change with the change in screen resolution

Comment: Then you should go with my solution. I think it will do that thing. try once

Comment: @Anirudha Hey check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/542576). It suggests to use `em` instead of `px`.