# disabling javascript zoom (CTRL + / CTRL-)

Tags: javascript, zooming

I'm Trying to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>  browsers shortcuts via javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey==true && (event.which == '107' || event.which == '109')) {
            alert('disabling zooming ! ');
            event.preventDefault();
         }
    });
});
```

This code is working great in FF and Chrome , and dosent prevent zooming in IE ! any idea ?

Comment: ["This is an accessibility issue and you should try to work with it and not against it."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542576/disable-the-ctrl-wheel-zoom-effect-at-runtime)

Comment: Why are you trying to disable the browser zoom?

Comment: I suspect the issue is with `event.preventDefault()`. You can try these solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1000597/1987993 . But I have to agree with jbabey, changing the expected behavior of the browser isn't a great idea, especially when it comes to accessibility features.

Comment: So many ways to trigger this zoom, including Ctrl+wheel, pinching gestures and menu items. You cannot prevent them all in all browsers on all platforms.

Comment: I Agree with jbabey too , but is there an answer to the question ?!

Comment: Did you try the solution in the link I provided?

Comment: Also, you may need to use event.keyCode instead of event.which for older versions of IE. I am not making an official answer because I don't have a computer with IE in front of me so I can't test it for you.

Comment: Warren R : I added  event.returnValue = false; inside the if and that doesn't work in IE

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, though you may want to bind to 'keyup' also.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).bind('keydown keypress', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Comment: This blocks ALL keyboard interaction with the page. That includes halting page load (ESC), scrolling (up, down, page up, page down, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There are more than 2 button numbers you have to preventDefault in order to disable fully the scrolling.
Me personally I disable all ctrl key combinations.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function preventDefault(e) {
          e = e || window.event;
          if (e.preventDefault)
              e.preventDefault();
          e.returnValue = false;
        }
    $(document).bind('keydown keypress', function (event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey) {
            preventDefault(event);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```